# 2D sprites in 3D space?

Tags: xna, sprites

How can I draw a 2D sprite to look like it's at a particular placement in the 3D world?

My goal is to use this as loose items in the world.

Minecraft Example: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-HMk5tW_cI-Y/TiYx71XkwtI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/jeaTfiMW1Ow/2011-07-19_20.26.18.png

Answer (score 9):

You'd render a quad in 3D space, using the sprite as the texture for that quad. You can [billboard](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125004311/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx) that quad so that it always faces the player (this is what Minecraft does for its non-block inventory items when they're on the ground, if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, this is done by rendering a single quad with the sprite applied to it as a texture.  The quad is generally rotated so that it always faces the player (usually only around the vertical axis).